# Difference between Debug and execute

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What is the difference between `Debug` and `Execute` in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I believe you are asking about Microsoft SQL Server database?

Comment: yes, it is Microsoft SQL server database

Comment: Then please check my answer. Hope it helps you understanding the basics.

Answer (score 3):

If you have worked on any other application programming languages e.g. C# or java then you must be aware of the terms `Debug` and `Run` in their respective Integrated Development Environments (IDE).

So `Debug` in SQL Server is same as `Debug` in any other programming language environment - You insert some break points in your code and the debugger stops right there while running your code from development environment. In SQL Server Management studio (SSMS) you have got a query window where you write some SQL code (aka script). Put some break points by pressing F9 key. Now when you press `Debug` the SQL Server engine starts executing your script statements one by one and stop whenever it encounters the first break point in your script.

Below is a snapshot where I've put two break points in a query window in SSMS:

[image]

`Execute` is equivalent to `Run` or running the code/script ignoring the break-points - SQL Server Management studio will simply execute your entire script present in your query window or selected script block without giving any consideration to the break points if you have inserted any at all.